# tag list made from specific category - wordpress

Tags: wordpress, categories, tag-cloud

Is this feature built into wordpress? i didnt see anything within the codex.

codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_tag_cloud

I have a few pages that are category specific and i would like to show all the tags associated with those posts.

I did find this, but im not sure if its proper or if a better way exists ([source](http://www.wprecipes.com/get-tags-specific-to-a-particular-category-on-your-wordpress-blog))(**old method!!!!**):

```
<?php
    query_posts('category_name=html');
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
        $posttags = get_the_tags();
        if ($posttags) {
            foreach($posttags as $tag) {
                $all_tags_arr[] = $tag -> name;
            }
        }
    endwhile; endif; 

    $tags_arr = array_unique($all_tags_arr);
?>
    <ul>
<?php
    foreach($tags_arr as $tag){
        echo '<li>'.$tag.'</li>';
    }
?>
</ul>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

**UPDATE( simplified ):::**

to make a list of tags from a specific category this code is much better(just change the category name):

::Recently updated again because of a loop error::

```
    <ul>
                <?php
                    query_posts('category_name=html');
                    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

                        if( get_the_tag_list() ){
                            echo $posttags = get_the_tag_list('<li>','</li><li>','</li>');
                        }

                    endwhile; endif; 

                    wp_reset_query(); 
                ?>
</ul>
```

Even tough i may have a solution, please update this if a new one comes around.

Comment: And how can you integrate this e.g. in the sidebar? Can you be more specific on the steps, where to paste the code, etc? Thank you!

Comment: The only thing the bottom bit of code relies on is the category_name that you put in. You can paste it anywhere you want. If you want it to show a tag list made from ONE category, put the category name in where it says 'html' and paste it anywhere you want.

Comment: This does not ignore duplicates. It shows the tag every time it appears within a post. Does anyone know of a way to ignore duplicates and show only unique tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the method you've found it's the only way you can achieve what you're looking for.
Maybe you can modify some lines, but the concept is right.

at the moment i don't think there's a way to filter tags as you would using a core wordpress function.

Comment: its funny because on my search for an answer, people have been asking this question as far as 3 years back(on the wordpress forums). Dont know why they didnt include it yet. oh well, this will do

Comment: maybe just because there are things more urgent to work on. if something can be achieved with 8 lines of code it's ok like that.

Comment: i managed to shorten the code with a wordpress function i found. it looks a bit better. I updated the question

Answer (score 2):

I did not get the code above to work my installation of WordPress. I did however manage to tweak it until it worked. Here is my tweak:

```
$catid = get_cat_ID(single_cat_title("",false));
$catobj = get_category($catid);
$catslug = $catobj->slug;
$all_tags_arr = array();
query_posts('category_name='.$catslug);
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $posttags = get_the_tags();
    if ($posttags) {
        foreach($posttags as $tag) {
            $all_tags_arr[] = $tag -> term_id;
        }
    }
endwhile; endif; 

$tags_arr = array_unique($all_tags_arr);

$tagcloud_args = array(
    'include'   =>  implode(',',$tags_arr),
);

wp_tag_cloud( $tagcloud_args ); 
wp_reset_query();
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a much easier example.... Just change the category name and hey presto your done. The associated tags will print out in a list format.

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=html'); if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    $posttags = get_the_tags();

    if ($posttags) {
        foreach($posttags as $tag) {
            $all_tags[] = $tag -> name;
        }
    }
    endwhile; endif; 

    //This snippet removes any duplicates.
    $tags_unique = array_unique($all_tags); 

    echo '<ul>';
        foreach($tags_unique as $unique) {
          echo  '<li>'.$unique.'</li>';
        }
    echo '</ul>';

    wp_reset_query();

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, install the ACF plugin and create a taxonomy field. After adding this below code where you want to display the tags.

```
$queriedObj = get_queried_object(); 
$taxonomy = $queriedObj->taxonomy;
$term_id = $queriedObj->term_id;  

$current_tags = get_field('category_tags', $taxonomy . '_' . $term_id); //category_tags = ACF fieldname

if ( $current_tags ) {
  echo '<ul>';
  foreach ( $current_tags as $term ) {
      echo '<li>';
      echo '<a href="/product-tag/' . $term->slug . '">';
      echo $term->name;
      echo '</a>';
      echo '</li>';
  }
  echo '</ul>';
}
else{
    echo '<ul>';
    echo '<li>No Tag.</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
}
```